# Is it feasible to use CiviPledge as a microloan management system?

Tags: civipledge

I haven't done much with CiviPledge but am curious about the potential of re-purposing it for a slightly different use to make CiviCRM work as a management tool for a nonprofit's microloan project. Would there be any downsides to doing something along these lines?

- Rename it with string replacement so "CiviPledge" becomes "CiviLoan", "pledge" becomes "loan", etc.
- Set up a "pledge" on an account when a microloan is given out.
- Record a "pledge payment" when a loan repayment is received.

Comment: I suppose the biggest hurdle would be the interest if they were not 0% interest loans.

Answer (score 3):

It could work, (but if there is an interest, as Laryn mentioned)

Two other tools you might want to look at:

1) civiCampaign: you could have one campaign per loan (with deadline an financial goal) and record the payments as donations associated to this campaign.

(probably easier than pledge if the frequency of the payments is not very regular)

2) civicase: if you have a lot of other activities around a microloan beside the financial one (eg if there is an approval process before the loan, if there is a set of action in case on delay on payments....)

have a look at civicase, it's a powerful tool that might take you some time to set up, but that will help you enforce consistent workflow to support your work